# read json object from mvc controller to dropdownlist

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, json, model-view-controller

In the actionresult, I wrote another function controller that initially converted the query output to .tolist (), and then sent the output as json.

```
var qry = searchFilter(sobj);
            var resultData = qry.ToList().Select(
                    u => new
                    {
                        RowId = 0,
                        u.Id,
                        u.Title
                    }).ToList();
            return Json(new { data = resultData }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
```

In the view I want to read json data on getjson and put it in html.dropdown with the following command:

```
$.getJSON('@Url.Action("GetData", "EduBranch", new { area="ManageLesson"})', null, function (data) {

            $.each(data, function (index, obj) {
                $('#col6_filter').append('<option value=' +
                  obj.Id + '>' + obj.Title + '</option>');
            });
        });
```

helper is as follows:

```
@Html.DropDownList("col6_filter", new SelectList(string.Empty, "Id", "Title"), "Please select..", new { @class = "form-control" })
```

But when running, the data shows undefined the dropdown. Where is the problem? Thank you for the help.

Comment: Did you check the response from the server? Is it OK?

Comment: The most suspicious is `new { data = resultData }` on `return Json`. Have you check `data` contents on `getJSON` method? And why `SelectList` content left blank for first time?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this return

```
return Json(resultData, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
```

or

```
 $.each(data.data, function (index, obj) {
            $('#col6_filter').append('<option value=' +
              obj.Id + '>' + obj.Title + '</option>');
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    make sure you have it like this in your controller
        return Json(resultData, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);

  --Your script--

    $.get("yourcontroller/Yourfunction",
         function (data) {
           $.each(data, function (i, datum) {
           $("#col6_filter").append('<option value="' + datum.Value + '">' + datum.Text + '</option>');
               });
              });
         });
```